# How to grant 'search' permission in SELinux

Tags: selinux

I am trying to get dspam working under SELinux (CentOS 7). I added the following without issue:

```
allow dspam_t dspam_rw_content_t:dir getattr;
allow dspam_t dspam_rw_content_t:file { append getattr lock open write };
```

However dspam still fails to work via procmail:

```
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/dspam: Permission denied
procmail: Program failure (126) of "/usr/bin/dspam"
```

When I set SELinux to permissive it works fine. I tried using `audit2allow` to identify what's missing:

```
[root@opus ~]# audit2allow -i /var/log/audit/audit.log
#============= dspam_t ==============
allow dspam_t dspam_rw_content_t:dir search;
```

But adding that to my policy causes `checkmodule` to error:

```
checkmodule:  loading policy configuration from OPUS.te
OPUS.te:19:ERROR 'permission search is not defined for class dir' at token ';' on line 19:
allow dspam_t dspam_rw_content_t:dir getattr;
allow dspam_t dspam_rw_content_t:dir search;
checkmodule:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
```

I have searched a bit but I am unable to find a solution. How would I add or define the `search` permission as indicated?

Comment: Your answer is probably to be found in [this article](https://blog.acmenet.ru/en/2014/12/02/dspam-centos-en/), but better indicate which of the described cases is yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't solve the end problem for me (dspam not working under SELinux enforcing mode) I am posting this because it does answer the actual question I asked (how to grant search permission).

Turns out I was missing `search` in the `require` block for this module.
I had:

```
require {
[...]
    class dir getattr;
}
```

When, as I discovered browsing the link in @harrymc's comment, I needed:

```
require {
[...]
    class dir { write getattr add_name search };
}
```

After this the module compiles and loads correctly.